# Scheduled task does not run on WIndows 2003 server on VMWare unattened, runs fine otherwise

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

Scheduled task does not run on Windows 2003 server on VMWare.  The same setup runs fine on standalone server.

Test below explains the problem.  We really need to run a more complex bat file, but this shows the issue.

I have a bat file that copies a file from server A to server B. I use full path name, no drive mapping.

Runs fine on server B from command prompt.

I created a task that runs this bat file under a domain id with password that is part of administrator group  on both servers.  Task runs fine from Scheduled task screen, and as a scheduled task as long as somebody is logged into the server.   If nobody is logged in, the task does not run.  There is no error message in Task Scheduler log, just an entry that the task started, bit no entry for finish or an error code.

To add insult to injury, if the task copies a file in the opposite direction, from server B to server A, it runs fine as a scheduled unattended task.

If I copy a file from server B to server B, the task also runs fine unattended,

I recreated exactly the same setup on a standalone server.  No issues at all.

I checked obvious things like the task has "run only as logged in" unchecked, domain id has run as a batch job privilege and logon rights, Task Scheduler service runs as a local system, automatic start.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What prorgram are you using to do the copy? I would use robocopy and set the logging attribute, and the verbose option.

Comment: The copy is not the problem, permissions are.  When I use the script that runs a utility (Oracle DRM batch utility) I get the same problem I get 0x64 task exit code (Network Issues).  Utility runs within the same server no network connection.  On non VMWare server the same program also runs fine by unattended scheduled task.  Something is wrong in VMWare interaction with Task Scheduler.  I was told that sync is not on, but it should not be the cause of this issue, because some tasks run fine unattended.  Only tasks that require specific permissions fail.

Comment: Are you using VMware tools to have the VM synchronize the VM's time with the ESXi host? I'm wondering if you're running into a clock issue that VMs run into when not using the CPU.

Comment: i don't have a windows box to test this so i can't provide a full answer. i had a similar problem in the past and it turned out to be a permission problem, find out what permissions are used exactly (e.g. with a batch job like 'whoami /all > c:\whoami.log'). probably you need to give to computer account the permissions on the target share. also the system (computer) account doesn't have a full environment, so you need to use full path to call the script

Answer (score 1):

Did you call VMWare Tech Support to see if they have any ideas about this?

I wrote everything below and then it occured to be, client firewall.  What port does Oracle DRM use and is it open on the VMWare Host?

Well it seems like you've got a couple of possibilities ...

- VMWare Problem
- Oracle DRM batch Problem
- Windows Task Scheduler Problem
- File Permission Problem
- Account Rights Problems

It seems like you checked permission/rights issues. I don't really know what to check for the Task Scheduler besides checking the event logs.

Did you try to do this with a different utility (besides Oracle DRM batch utility)?
Did you try a copy something else like a text file using Oracle DRM?
Did you try to use Oracle DRM batch utility to do something remotely over then copying, like run a program?